# I am getting column not found from inner query in spite of using an alias

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I am new to SQL and I want to basically derive a quartile graph from my query. However the I have ran into some issues with my query

I have given aliases and I am trying to calculate quartiles.

Here is the query

```
SELECT series,
       MIN(value) AS minimum,
       AVG(q1) AS q1,
       AVG(median) AS median,
       AVG(q3) AS q3,
       MAX(value) AS maximum
FROM 
    (SELECT series,
            PERCENTILE_CONT(0.25) WITHIN GROUP 
                 (ORDER BY value) OVER (PARTITION BY series) AS q1,
            MEDIAN(value) OVER (PARTITION BY series) AS median,
            PERCENTILE_CONT(0.75) WITHIN GROUP 
                 (ORDER BY value) OVER (PARTITION BY series) AS q3
     FROM  
         (SELECT type as series, (a.duration)/(60000) as value
          FROM test.pattern a
          JOIN test.metadata b ON a.id = b.id) AS quartile) AS raw_data
GROUP BY 1
```

However I keep getting

```
column "value" does not exist in raw_data
```

My column name doesnot have any upper cases and this is really confusing me now.

I would appreciate the help

**UPDATE:**
Thanks to Gordan, the query is working. However the execution time is really slow for a large dataset, Any pointers on how that could be improved
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select it in the *middle* subquery as well:

```
FROM (SELECT series, value,
---------------------^
             PERCENTILE_CONT(0.25) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY value) OVER (PARTITION BY series) AS q1,
             MEDIAN(value) OVER (PARTITION BY series) AS median,
             PERCENTILE_CONT(0.75) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY value) OVER (PARTITION BY series) AS q3
      FROM (SELECT type as series, (a.duration)/(60000) as value
                FROM test.pattern p JOIN
                     test.metadata m
                     ON p.id = m.id
          ) AS quartile
     ) AS raw_data
```

Comment: Thank you!! I got it working. However this query takes a very long time. Any pointer how I can improve the performance

Comment: @YogeshSingh . . . You should ask another question about performance.  Be sure to include the query, explain what it is doing, and providing sizing and index information about the tables.